# How to find the modified ActionForm bean in struts

Tags: struts

I have a requirement in struts 1.2 framework where i have 50 to 60 fields in my form in which i have to update only 3 Fields(which are changed by the user) so when i submit the form,only these 3 Fields needs to be updated in the database.

How can i identify the 3 changed/modified fields out of 50 fields in the struts ActionForm.
Your suggestions are very mush appreciated.

Comment: If you know that only 3 fields must be updated, what's the point of displaying the 47 to 57 other ones? How can you know that only 3 fields must be updated without knowing which ones. I don't understand.

Comment: Hi JB Nizet Thank you for you reply,Actually User can modify all the 50 to 60 Fields But not all the time they will modify all the 60 fields some time they will modify only 3 to fields so i have to update only these fields in Database.I heard PropertyChangeListener that will trigger if the user change the value of the bean but that is for SWING application usually that will not be used for MVC Web application.Actually i'm looking for valueChangeListener in JSF but in JSP we don't have valueChangeListener is there any alternative solution available in JSP or Struts.Highly need your assistance.

Comment: When the user submits a form, he submits all its fields. Even if he hasn't modified oe of the fields, he has chosen to leave it as it was, and thus wants this value to be saved. Just save all the fields: that's what te user wants. That said, 50 fields on a single form is way too much.

Comment: Hi JB Nizet again Thank you for you reply,Yes we can save all the fields but these fields are from different table may be i get the values of the field from 5Tables.So every time updating the table even the values are not changed is a big performance issue.(ex)If the user changes some 3 fields that belong to only one table then update that table alone don't update other table it will save our time.I hope you understand clearly.

Answer (score 0):

There's no way to do this since when you submit the form you're submitting all the fields (except checkboxes, sometime).

You could use javascript and ajax to just post the values you want to change.  Set an event handler on your fields to detect that the user changed them and post just your changed fields.  The problem with this is that you can only use javascript to submit the 'form' if you go that route.

Personally what I would do is create a javabean that you can populate from your form that just contains the 3 fields that you're checking if they changed or not.  Grab the current data from the db (or you can use a session attribute if you don't want to query again) and populate another instance of your javabean with that data.  Compare the two beans to see if the fields are equal.  Process the rest of the form based on the equality of the beans you're comparing.

Or as long as you're using an actionform to populate the fields to begin with, compare the actionform that the user submitted with another one populated with fresh data to determine what you actually need to persist.

Comment: Thank you int21h,That i did already actually i'm looking for some other simple alternative solution if possible in struts.I can't do this in javascript and ajax.Anyway thank you for your precious help.